# Find a value in a column in the entire workbook and ad it into a Textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have created this Userform.

[image]

What I want to accomplish is that I want this TextBox (blue circle) to be filled with a number taken from the workbook. This number will be obtained in column A:A and if say this number is 1 I want the Userform TextBox to display 2 (always add +1).

I Have the following code that I have written:

```
TextBoxLopnummer.Value = Sheets("Energi").Range("MAX(A:A)+1").Value
```

But an error occurs which dispalys "Runtime error 1004"

Comment: I managed to solve it and the solution is: `Dim ws As Worksheet, currentmax As Integer currentmax = 0 For Each ws In Worksheets currentmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(currentmax, ws.Columns("A:A")) Next ws 'Lopnummer.Value = currentmax + 1 ' or if you need 4 digits formatting TextBoxLopnummer.Value = Format(currentmax + 1, "0000")`

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post the solution as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This: Range("MAX(A:A)+1") will not give you the Max value in the range. Try this:

```
TextBoxLopnummer.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Energi").Range("A:A")) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, currentmax As Integer
currentmax = 0

For Each ws In Worksheets
    currentmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(currentmax, ws.Columns("A:A"))
Next ws

TextBoxLopnummer.Value = Format(currentmax + 1, "0000") 'or if you need 4 digits formatting
```